# Syslog floods when adb server is running

Tags: android, linux, adb, syslog

I have a Linux box, and I notice whenever I run `adb`, tons of garbage messages flood into syslog, such as:

```
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: hub_resume
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: port 1: status 0507 change 0000
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: state 7 ports 2 chg 0000 evt 0000
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: usb 1-1: usb auto-resume
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: GetStatus port:1 status 001005 0  ACK POWER sig=se0 PE CONNECT
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: usb 1-1: finish resume
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: hub_resume
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: reused qh ffff8800b700d980 schedule
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: usb 1-1: link qh256-0001/ffff8800b700d980 start 1 [1/0 us]
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: state 7 ports 6 chg 0000 evt 0000
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: hub_suspend
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: usb 1-1: unlink qh256-0001/ffff8800b700d980 start 1 [1/0 us]
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: usb 1-1: usb auto-suspend, wakeup 1
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: hub_suspend
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: usb usb1: bus auto-suspend, wakeup 1
Mar 09 17:22:39 laptoo kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: suspend root hub
Mar 09 17:22:40 laptoo kernel: usb usb1: usb auto-resume
Mar 09 17:22:40 laptoo kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: resume root hub
Mar 09 17:22:40 laptoo kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: hub_resume
Mar 09 17:22:40 laptoo kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: port 1: status 0507 change 0000
Mar 09 17:22:40 laptoo kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: state 7 ports 2 chg 0000 evt 0000
Mar 09 17:22:40 laptoo kernel: usb 1-1: usb auto-resume
Mar 09 17:22:40 laptoo kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: GetStatus port:1 status 001005 0  ACK POWER sig=se0 PE CONNECT
```

They only disappear after I enter `adb kill-server`. Is there a way to get rid of them while ADB server is running?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the usbcore autosuspend value. First checkout the current value,

```
  cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

Then, change it to something you want. Or, if you want you can set it to -1:

```
  echo -1 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

Note: this will prevent autosuspend on any usb devices.

Comment: @chys - you don't see the option? Maybe you don't have it enabled, it depends on CONFIG_PM_RUNTIME option.

Comment: It's enabled, the current value is 2.